# Is python bisect faster than numpy.searchsorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was surprised to see that python's [bisect.bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) was faster than the numpy equivalent [numpy.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy-searchsorted). Is that related to the distribution of values I used or will this remain true for any input?

```py
>>> input_size = 10**3
>>> input_list = sorted([random.uniform(0, 300) for _ in range(input_size)])
>>> numpy_input = np.array(input_list)

>>> %timeit index = bisect.bisect_left(input_list, 100)
434 ns ± 6.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit index = np.searchsorted(numpy_input, 100)
1.8 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Python is on version 3.8.0 and numpy on version 1.18.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you're doing one lookup at a time. One scalar at a time is not an efficient way to use NumPy.

Calling `searchsorted` with an entire array of elements to find is faster than calling `bisect_left` with one element at a time in a loop:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import bisect

In [3]: numpy_haystack = numpy.arange(300)

In [4]: list_haystack = numpy_haystack.tolist()

In [5]: numpy_needles = numpy.arange(5, 150, 3)

In [6]: list_needles = numpy_needles.tolist()

In [7]: %timeit numpy.searchsorted(numpy_haystack, numpy_needles)
2.39 µs ± 71.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: for needle in list_needles:
   ...:     bisect.bisect_left(list_haystack, needle)
   ...:
18.4 µs ± 1.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I would have though that even the lookups required to search for the value would make the numpy solution faster (I guess both do O(log n) lookups). Why isn't that true?

Comment: @cglacet: NumPy has higher per-call overhead. Also, `bisect` is written in C, so it doesn't have the bytecode interpretation overhead a pure-Python implementation would have. (It still has to do per-element dynamic dispatch and follow more pointers, though, since it's working with an ordinary Python list.)

Comment: "NumPy has higher per-call overhead" oh ok, I see, that's the information I didn't had. It's hard as end user to get a grip on these important "details". Thanks for your help guiding me a bit close to this goal :D.